# Need to save dialogflow conversations logs to database via webhook url

Tags: dialogflow-es

Need to save dialogflow conversations logs to database via webhook url.
Currently using the Twilio autopilot functionality where webhooks option allow to trigger the logs in real time to webhook url where can be save logs in database.
Same thing need to implement in dialogflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In dialogflow, interact with users using chatbots conversations. Need to logs all these chatbots conversations logs in real time in database so that perform some actions on these at our end. Please help to implement this in dialogflow.

Comment: Please suggest on this.